# Existence of a global section of $L(D)$ vanishing on $D$.

Tags: complex-geometry, line-bundles

Given a complex surface $X$ and $D$ a smooth curve on $X$, there is an associated line bundle $L(D)$ over $X$. Is there always a global section $s\in H^0(X,L(X))$, s.t. $s$ is just vanishing on $D$?

Comment: You mean $L(D)$. Yes. Review how the line bundle is constructed in terms of transition functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin are you using the Cartier divisor to be our global section since in this case when $D$ is a hypersurface, the corresponding Cartier divisor happens to be a holomorphic function vanishing on D?

Comment: Close, but no. When $X$ is compact, the only global holomorphic functions are constants. So you need to go back to open coverings ...